# how do I space things in a node in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, baseline

I want to be able to add more space between the z and w in their node. I tried bigskip and other things (including redefining baselineskip), and the two words (in the original document) still seem very tight. It seems like the medskip/bigskip commands get ignored inside a node?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cc/.style={minimum height=1.21cm,align=center,fill=green!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},cred/.style={minimum height=1.21cm,align=center,fill=green!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},cgreen/.style={minimum height=1.21cm,align=center,fill=green!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},corange/.style={minimum height=1.21cm,align=center,fill=green!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm}]

\path (0,0) node[cc] (A) {x} (2.3,0) node[cc] (B) {z \bigskip \\ w} (4.6,0) node[cc] (C) {t\\v} (6.8,0) node[cc] (D) {CC \\ CC};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding to the other answers, also `\vspace{5cm}` (exaggerated)should work instead of using the `\bigskip` .

Comment: Note that `align=center` creates a one column tabular inside the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm and 4mm,
  start chain = going right,
    cc/.style = {fill=#1, rounded corners=2pt,
                 minimum height=1.21cm, minimum width=18mm, align=center,
                 inner sep=4, outer sep=0,
                 on chain},
    cc/.default = green!20
                        ]
\node[cc] (A) {x};
\node[cc] (B) {z\\[2ex] w}; % <---
\node[cc] (C) {t\\v};
\node[cc] (D) {CC\\ CC};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes. strange, but it works! it seems like it forces the box to become bigger, so maybe that was the problem? bigskip etc. was doing all of that within the bounds of the box?

Comment: @kloop, it  is not strange ... your way to inserting `\bigskip` is wrong.  It should be after line termination (`\\`) ... As I see, in this particular case all boxes have the same haights (as you defined in your MWE)